# Load testing html and objects embedded with yandex.tank

Tags: load-testing, yandex, yandex-tank

I have been using yandex.tank for a few days to perform load tests

I have set up the URL's list in different ways but I do not get my goal

I want to simulate a real visit (like a web navigator):

1. request
2. html response
3. request of objects embedded in the code

I can create a grouped list of the objects embedded in the code, but the results are oriented to each of the requests per individual. For example:

My "home" tag in "Cumulative Cases Info" shows me:

4554 28.21% / avg 171.2 ms

171.2 ms is the average time of each of the objects. I want the average time for the full request (html and embeded objects)

Is it possible to perform a load test by making requests like those indicated with yandex.tank? Or with another load testing tool?

Answer (score 0):

Yandex-tank (actually default load generator Phantom in it), doesn't parse response and therefore knows nothing about embedded resources. You'd better try jmeter as a load generator, since it's HTTP Request Sampler has an option to retrieve resources - http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request

Comment: Upd: if you prefer yandex-tank console statistic, it's possible to use jmeter as a load generator in yandex-tank http://yandextank.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core_and_modules.html#jmeter
In that case, the results could be uploaded to web server http://yandextank.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core_and_modules.html#yandex-overload, here is an example of report - https://overload.yandex.net/504